# Discrepancy in ATR called through the security function

Tags: pine-script

I have a client that wants to use behavior that involves an indicator on a Renko chart. The behavior depends on ATR. ATR values do not match when using the security function. So, while on a traditional 1.2 period renko chart:

```
ohlca()=>
    o = open
    h = high
    l = low
    c = close
    a = atr(14)
    [o,h,l,c,a]
[o,h,l,c,a] = ohlca()
[o2, h2, l2, c2, a2] = security(renko(syminfo.tickerid, 'Traditional', 1.2), timeframe.period, ohlca(), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

plotchar(o,'o','')
plotchar(o2,'o2','')
plotchar(h,'h','')
plotchar(h2,'h2','')
plotchar(l,'l','')
plotchar(l2,'l2','')
plotchar(c,'c','')
plotchar(c2,'c2','')
plotchar(a,'a','')
plotchar(a2,'a2','')
```

Most of the values match, aside from timing discrepancies. But the ATR is up to 80% off sometimes. Does anyone know what is causing this behavior and how to work around it? Unfortunately the request is to make the trade behavior work how the indicator looks on the renko chart, the indicator being a moving average displaced by ATR.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to displaying wicks, and having the source set to OHLC on the Renko Chart Settings.

The `renko()` function has no options for source or wicks. It does not return highs or lows (they will be the same as the open or close) so the chart settings must be set to not display wicks, and source as Close for the values to match.